# How to set apt-get option for a specific source?

Tags: command-line, apt

Is there a way to set `apt-get` option only for a specific source? for example: I'd like avoid signature check for the packages pulled from a local source. As far as I understood, If create a custom conf file under `/etc/apt/pat.conf` and include

```
APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated
```

it'll be applicable to all sources, how do I limit the above single source? (eg: `/etc/apt/sources.d/myown.list`)

Comment: You can  add custom repo as `deb [trusted=yes] file:/path`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to fetch your `.deb`s  only from one single source, right?

Then you can set the /etc/apt/sources.list to old using

```
# mv  /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.listold #or something like that
```

then create a new sources.list using

```
# touch /etc/apt/sources.list
```

after that edit the new sources.list using

```
# vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

finaly insert a line like that:

```
deb http://name.of.your.server/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://name.of.your.server/ubuntu/ precise universe
```

Now apt will fetch only packages from name.of.your.server

I hope this will help you.

Comment: nope, the question was to set some specific option to the .deb files pulled from a specific source, See totti's comment to the question, that's what I was looking for.